# How to show network adapter name instead of full device name

Tags: c#, network-interface

Im making an application which does something with netsh. However, the Wireless network adapter should be selected by the user via a combo box. Unfortunately, it shows the entire device name( eg. "Realtek RTL8188CU Wireless LAN adapter") instead of Wi-Fi, as seen under network centre > networkadapters.
I'm trying to make it read the Wi-Fi part, which in some languages is diffrent if i recall correctly, and the name must be correct for my program to work.

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if ((nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211) && (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up))
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(nic.Description);
            }
        }
```

this is what i want to read, to be clear. I already ensure any virtual connections or wired connections do not show. https://puu.sh/w1LFb/6c19a16ebc.png

Comment: `NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211` is WiFi.

Comment: `comboBox1.Items.Add("MUH WIFFY");` what's the problem here?

Comment: It shows the full device name, i need the name you see in network adapters. Which sometimes is called "Wi-Fi" and sometimes "Wireless network adaptor", my program depends on that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if ((nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211) && (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up))
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(nic.Name);
        }
    }
```